# Lua LÖVE automate variable names

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm writing a lua LÖVE program as a school project.

> The task is something about ants, that need to find food, take some to the nest they came from and on the way leaving a trace of pheromons. In addition we've write a program visualizing the process. For 100 ants, 5 food sources and all this in a space of 500x500 squares

I chose lua LÖVE for the visualization and wrote the following code:

```
function love.load()
    p = 500 -- Starting position

    xNest, yNest = p, p -- Initializing nest position

    xAnt1, yAnt1 = p, p -- Initializing ant position
    xAnt2, yAnt2 = p, p


end

-- Changes position every frame.
function love.update(dt)

-- AntI // See what I did there?
    xAnt1 = xAnt1 + math.random (-2, 2) -- Change position by a random number between 2 steps forward and 2 steps backward
    yAnt1 = yAnt1 + math.random (-2, 2) -- Change position by a random number between 2 steps sideways

    xAnt2 = xAnt2 + math.random (-2, 2) 
    yAnt2 = yAnt2 + math.random (-2, 2)
end



-- Draw ants and nest.
function love.draw()

    -- Nest 
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 255) -- set drawing color green
    love.graphics.rectangle("line", xNest, yNest, 2, 2) -- draw a nest at xNest, yNest with a size of 2x2

    -- Ant
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255) -- set drawing color white
    love.graphics.rectangle("line", xAnt1, yAnt1, 2, 2) -- draw an ant at xAnt(number of ant), yAnt(number of ant) with a size of 2x2
    love.graphics.rectangle("line", xAnt2, yAnt2, 2, 2)

end
```

Since my task is to do what I did in 
`xAntX, yAntX = p, p` 100 times, whereby X I mean the number for the ant, I need some kind of loop that creates `xAntX, yAntX = p, p`, `xAntX = xAntX + math.random (-2, 2)` ,  `yAntX = yAntX + math.random (-2, 2)` and  `love.graphics.rectangle("line", xAntX, yAntX, 2, 2` a 100 times.

I tried a for loop, but it always yelled at me for trying to append a variable ´i´ to the initialization `xAnt .. i, yAnt .. i` and then count i++ with `i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `xAnt` and `yAnt` tables, and access individual entries as `xAnt[i]` and `yAnt[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is quite old, if you're new to Lua and ended up here with the same question, I'd like to propose a different solution which is in my opinion more elegant than the accepted answer:

One simple method of storing multiple properties in a structured way is to store them as nested "object"-like tables in an "array"-like table. For example, initialise an empty `ants` table like so:

```lua
local ants = {}
```

Then, use a [numeric for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) to add the desired amount of ants to the `ants` table:

```lua
for i = 1, 100 do
  ants[#ants + 1] = { x: ..., y: ... }
end
```

Each ant itself is also a table, but instead of numeric keys, it uses string keys. See Lua's [documentation on tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) for more information. Now, you can loop over all the ants in the list and update each ant using:

```lua
for _, ant in ipairs(ants) do
  ant.x = ant.x + math.random(-2, 2)
  ant.y = ant.y + math.random(-2, 2)
end
```

Specific ants may be updated directly through their index. To update the second ant, use `ants[2]`.

The benefit of this approach is that you only have one global variable which holds all your ants, instead of having separate global variables for each individual property of each ant. This generally makes the code easier to reason about and aids in debugging as well.

Happy developing fellow Luanatics :D